# Can a Double 12 Domino set function as two Double 6 domino sets?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

If I subtract 6 from any domino with pips more than 6, do I effectively create two double 6 sets from a single double 12 set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you have too many dominoes. Also you won't even have the same number of copies of everything. You will get four copies of most dominoes, three copies of doubles other than 0:0, one copy of 0:0 and two copies of any other domino with a 0 on.

You can get two complete double-six sets by removing all dominoes with no 0 and exactly one side greater than 6, except for 6:12, then subtracting 6 from numbers greater than 6, but treating 6:12 as 0:0.

Comment: Thank you. This is the logic I needed fleshed out.

Comment: I think, that all the dominoes with $6$ should stay.

Comment: You're right that some extra dominoes need to stay, but I think it's the ones with 0 which should be left in. I'll edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. In each domino set there should be a $(0,0)$ domino. If you subtract 6 from both tiles, $(0,0)$ domino will be created only from $(6,6)$ domino, which appears only once in double 12 domino set.

Also there are too many dominoes - double 12 domino set contains 91 dominoes, double 6 domino set only $21$.

Of course you can subtract two double 6 domino sets (one, where each tile has value greater or equal 6, and second, where each tile has value smaller of equal 6 except $(6,6)$ plus $(0,7)$ that will function as $(6,6)$.